# How to limit the native memory usage for Android?

Tags: android, testing, memory-leaks, process, native

I'm testing a memory leak in native libraries. The test case looks like this:

```
while (true) {
  doIt();
}
```

Every time `doIt()` is executed, a tiny little amount of memory is leaked, so it takes a long time for the application to crash.

My question is: how to lower the native memory an application is allowed to use so that I can crash the application sooner?

Comment: @CommonsWare what about in normal linux systems? how's android different from that?

Comment: I cannot comment regarding capping the memory consumption of a process in Linux, but the odds of there being a way to do that, and a way that you can do that on an Android device to a Dalvik process forked from the zygote, are fairly small.

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you saying that it is unlikely because the dalvik process is forked from zygote and inherits its properties? If that's true, it won't help either if we do it in an emulator, right?

Comment: I am saying that because Android is not a full Linux environment (lacking various tools you might use to control this normally, if there are any), because Android is not a normal Linux environment (and the changes they made might interfere with your aims), and because you do not control the actual Linux executable (where there may be ways to cap memory consumption as a compile-time operation).